# Setting up custom UILabel

Tags: ios, fonts, uilabel

I want to get a `UILabel` with same background and font as in this image.

[image]

Comment: This ain't [Howcast](http://m.howcast.com/promos/iphone), [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 2):

Simple, First drag and drop a label.

[image]

Select your label, then you can adjust its attributes by doing the following.

Define a custom font color.

[image]

Choose the font that you feel best matches what you are looking for.

[image]

Change your background color.

[image]

Or for the gradient effect as the label background you can do this by setting an image as the background like so.

```
theLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blah"]];
```

I've guided you through the steps of making this happen, but for future reference, you won't get a very good response on this website simply by asking someone to do your work for you.